# Doxygen-produced PDF - change url color?

Tags: doxygen

I’m using Doxygen 1.8.10 (on Windows) to generate LaTeX files, and MiKTex 2.9 to generate a PDF. The PDF is functional, but not very pretty. I’ve figured out how to customize the title page (I added graphics and non-default text) and how to get the images into the PDF.

But... how do I change the styling for things such as the color of URLs (which are just text in the Doxygen comments, and then Doxygen turns them into \href items)?

**** I believe I need to change something in the hyperref package’s config or what Doxygen writes to the .tex files, but I’m not sure which approach is right, nor how to do either one...

I’ve created a custom_doxygen.sty file, and assigned it to the LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET. I assume that it’s being picked up by Doxygen because Doxygen is successfully picking up my custom LATEX_HEADER file, which is in the same directory as the custom_doxygen.sty file. But what I don’t know is what to put into the custom_doxygen.sty file?

If I run everything as default (that is, no LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET), the following code gets written to the refman.tex file:

```
% Hyperlinks (required, but should be loaded last)
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[ps2pdf,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  unicode%
}
```

And what I need is for the “urlcolor” to also be blue (its default in the hyperref package is magenta—an odd choice for sure).

I tried just basically copying what was in the refman.tex file to the custom_doxygen.sty file (and making sure that the custom_doxygen.sty file *is* assigned to the LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET setting in my Doxyfile) and adding a “urlcolor=blue,%” to the setup section, but there’s no change in the output.

If I manually edit the refman.tex file (that is, I add "citecolor=blue,%" to the \hypersetup) after it's output from Doxygen, and then use the edited file as input to MiKTeX, I get the desired output.

So a workaround could be to just script the desired change and run the script every time. But it would be certainly be better to get Doxygen to write the necessary configuration. Plus, there are other things I want to customize (such as the font of explicit html hrefs), so I'd like to learn how to do things properly.